# How to use rpath with LLD linker (LLVM)

Tags: g++, llvm, lld

I recently managed to use the lld linker in a big cmake project. (LLVM 11, [from this package](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-lld?repo=mingw64))
I do not use clang, I use G++ with LLD.

But I encounter the following issue: `lld: error: unknown argument: -rpath`

Following the clang documentation, -rpath [should work](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-rpath), at least with clang I guess ?

Here is the g++ command generated by cmake:

```
g++.exe  [...] -fuse-ld=lld [...] -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN' [...]
```

I manually tried a lot of combinations:

```
-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'
-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'
-Wl,-rpath '$ORIGIN'
```

... etc, nothing work.

Of what I understand, lld should behave exactly like ld ?, so -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN' should work ?
Did I miss something ?

Comment: I have the same problem, documentation is not clear, other reports that only `-Wl,-rpath,` should work, but I can't either.